# Fail to import module 'webbrowser'

Tags: python, python-3.5

```
import webbrowser
```

This causes an error:

> ImportError: No module named 'webbrowser'

I want open an URL using `webbrowser`. How can I do this?

Comment: `'webbroswer' != 'webbrowser'`

Comment: What moduel are you looking for? Does a module called `webbrowser` exist?

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe

Comment: @DisplayName https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The module may be not installed so ,

1. open a shell and start the python shell by typing python
2. enter the commmand help('modules')
3. review the list of modules that's returned to see whether webbroswer is included
4. if not, then install the module

Comment: where can i download module 'webbrowser'?

Comment: @강병찬 before that please go and see whether your spelling is correct. webbrowser / webbroswer

Comment: The module is in the standard library, it doesn't need installing

Comment: @강병찬 , please, consider to upvote the answer if you got help. It will helpful other with the same kind of issue.